# ios: How to add remote audio file to AVAudioMix

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am developing a simple video editor on ios using AVFoundation. one part of the video editor is to mix an audio which is saved remotely. 
for eg: 
http://zfete.com/sample.mp4

now i am using AVAudioMix to mix an audio track which is working fine for local files. how can i use AVAudioMix to add a remote audio track.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: NSURL *url = .............AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];NSArray *keys = @[@"tracks"];[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() { NSError *error = nil; AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error]; switch (status) { case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: [self processTracks]; break; case AVKeyValueStatusFailed: [self reportError:error forAsset:asset]; break; case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled: // Do whatever is appropriate for cancelation. break; }}];

Comment: again i have the same problem. i think the above code is for local files. thank you.

Comment: what error your getting ? NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"your string"]; used this right ?

Comment: actually i am using :  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://inwiter.com/usermedia/audios/Castles.mp4"]];
        
        audioAsset = playerItem.asset;
        NSArray *requestedKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kTracksKey, kPlayableKey, nil];

Comment: [audioAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:
         ^{
                NSError *error=nil;
                AVKeyValueStatus status = [audioAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
                switch (status)
                {
                    case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: //[self processTracks];
                         NSLog(@"Tracks Loaded.....");
                         break;

Comment: case AVKeyValueStatusFailed: //[self reportError:error forAsset:asset]; break;
                    
                    case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled: break;
                }
                 
         }];

Comment: actually the tracks are loading perfectly. but When i am adding the asset To AVAudioMix its not working.